# How to apply onclick event to html tag when it displays in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I created a Php page which retrieves data from MySQL database. I inserted four records into database. the data displays fine on index.php page but I want to display record like shown in image attached here. I want that all records are closed and when click on name it will open. other are remain closed and when other is open previous is closed. right now when run in browser when I click any name only first record is display. (Or any other way to do this with php,MySQL,etc.) Any help ?
[image]

index.php :

```
<?php

ob_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'test');

$connection = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

$select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample order by id desc");
$i=1;
while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select))

{
$id=$userrow['id'];
$username=$userrow['username'];
$usercity=$userrow['usercity'];
$useraddress=$userrow['useraddress'];
$usermail=$userrow['emailid'];
$usermobile=$userrow['mobileno'];
$created=$userrow['created']
?>
<div class="display" style="width:500px">
<!-------------------- User Name : --------------------------------->
  <p id="User-Name" style="color:#999" onclick="showDiv();"> Name- <span style="color: #999"><?php echo $username; ?></span>
  <span class="delete" title="Delete"> X </span></a>
  </p>
  <br />
<!--------------------- User City : ----------------------------------->
  <p style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -45px; color:#999">City- <span style="color:#999"><?php echo $usercity; ?></span></p>
  <br />

  <div id="Entries" >
<!---------------------- User address : -------------------------------->
  <p style="color:#999">Address-  <span style="color:#999"><?php echo $useraddress; ?></span>

  </p>
  <br />
<!------------------ User Email Id : -------------------------------->  
  <p style="color:#999">Email-  <span style="color:#999"><?php echo $usermail; ?></span>
    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><span class="edit" title="Edit"> E </span></a>
  </p>
<!--------------------- User Mobile : --------------------------------->
  <br />
  <p style="color:#999">Mobile-  <span style="color:#999"><?php echo $usermobile; ?></span>
  </p>
 <!-------------------- User Created : -------------------------------> 
  <br />
  <p style="color:#999">  <span style="color:#999"><?php echo $created; ?></span>
  </p>
  <br />
  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<script>
function showDiv() 
{
  document.getElementById('Entries').style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<style>
#Entries
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Because of while loop when I run index.php the "Display" div shows all records on the page but "Display" div is replicate so, onclick event also replicate. their for onclick event fire once when I click on any name and display first record everytime. How to solve this !

Comment: Instead of `id` for `Entries`, try to change that one to `class` and test it again. Because `id` can be work for the first one. 
And also change `getElementByClassName()` in you function.

Comment: yes I try that but data inside "Entries" div is hidden no activity on clicking on names. I think onclick="showDiv(); is unique. I think that if dynamicaly onclick event is assign like showDiv1() for record 1 and so on then problem is solved but how ?

Comment: Accordion is best for this situation
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I try "Accordion" is good for static data. but, because "Entries" div is in loop it will duplicate so the <div id="accordion"> is also repeate and conflict and only first record is display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a document id is unique , this means only one id can be provided, So change your `<div id="Entries" >` to `<div class="Entries" >` (while loop print the same div tag many times).

Now change your onclick event from `<p>` to `<div>` like this:
`<p style="color:#999" onclick="showDiv();">` change to `<div class="display" onclick="showDiv(this);" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:2px;">`(Then only you can select the 'div.Entries' which is inside div.display , not inside `<p>`) 

 
Now change your css style tag at the bottom of your code from `#Entries`to `.Entries`(because we changed in the div)

Just add the following code to your page

```
<script>
function showDiv(obj) 
{
    $('.Entries').css('display','none');
 var div = $(obj).find('.Entries').css('display','block');
}
</script>
```

The compleated code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
      <?php

      $database = array(
      'one' => array('name' => 'john' , 'city' => 'noida' , 'addr' => 'xyz','mail' => 'john@xyz.com'),
      'two' => array('name' => 'jimi' , 'city' => 'india' , 'addr' => 'abc','mail' => 'jimi@abc.com'),
      'three' => array('name' => 'foo' , 'city' => 'china' , 'addr' => 'pqr','mail' => 'foo@pqr.com'),
      'four' => array('name' => 'apple' , 'city' => 'america' , 'addr' => 'lmno','mail' => 'apple@lmno.com'),
      );

           foreach ($database as $row) {

            $username = $row['name'];
            $usercity = $row['city'];
            $useraddress = $row['addr'];
            $usermail = $row['mail'];

        echo    '<div class="display" onclick="showDiv(this);" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:2px;">
            <!-------------------- User Name : --------------------------------->
              <p style="color:#999"> Name- <span style="color: #999">'.$username.' ?></span>
              <span class="delete" title="Delete"> X </span></a>
              </p>
              <br />
            <!--------------------- User City : ----------------------------------->
              <p style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -45px; color:#999">City- <span style="color:#999">'.$usercity.'</span></p>
              <br />

              <div class="Entries" >
            <!---------------------- User address : -------------------------------->
              <p style="color:#999">Address-  <span style="color:#999">'.$useraddress.'</span>

              </p>
              <br />
            <!------------------ User Email Id : -------------------------------->  
              <p style="color:#999">Email-  <span style="color:#999">'.$usermail.'</span>
                <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><span class="edit" title="Edit"> E </span></a>
              </p>
              <br />
              </div>
            </div>';
    }

      ?>

</body>
<script>
function showDiv(obj) 
{
    $('.Entries').css('display','none');
 var div = $(obj).find('.Entries').css('display','block');
}
</script>

<style>
.Entries
{
  display:none;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It's really helpful I just modify loop foreach not working in my case so while loop is working fine and my awaited problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$('div.display').click(function() {
    // hide all the divs
    $('div.display').css('display', 'none');

    // display only the current one using $(this) reference
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

EDIT:

Add `class="username"` to the username `<p>` element

Add `class="entries"` to the Entries `<div` element

Change the code to

```
$('.username').click(function() { 
    // hide all the divs
    $('div.entries').css('display', 'none');

    // display only the current one using $(this).parent() reference
    // because you are clicking the username element
    $(this).parent().css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: I try above j Query code but nothing happens ! What should I do ?

Comment: Did you put it in `<script>` tags and also include jQuery in your `.html` file? Copy this in your `<head>` : `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: $('#User-Name').click(function() {
    $('#Entries.display').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
});         I try this but nothing happens.....!

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `user_id` to that function so that it will be unique function for respective div. Also give that div unique id like `id="user_info_panel_<?php echo $user_id; ?>"`

eg:

```
$user_id: 2;
onclick="return clickme($user_id);"
```

Comment: Ok I can try.......... But, how I give a "Unique" id to div because it is only one as you seen in code. when I run index.php that <div class="display"> is returns number of records in browser so, the whole tags and properties inside <div class="display"> are cloned for each record. So how can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `id` value must be unique on an HTML page for every element.  As such, your collection of `<div>` elements that hold the database information shold be assigned a `class` rather than an `id`.

[jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/f3h6obdd/2/)

**Documentation:**

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

[.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
    var $entryCollectionArray = $('div.entries')
     $entryCollectionArray.click(function(i) {
      var $brothers = $(this).siblings();
      var $activeEntry = $(this);
      $brothers.addClass('notActive').removeClass('active');
      $activeEntry.addClass('active');
      if ($activeEntry.addClass('active')) {
        $activeEntry.animate({
          height: '120px'
        }, 550);

        $brothers.animate({
          height: '18px'
        }, 550);
      }
    });
```

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ACE;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='entries'>
  mySQL 1
</div>
<div class='entries'>
  mySQL 2
</div>
<div class='entries'>
  mySQL 3
</div>
<div class='entries'>
  mySQL 4
</div>
```